# Loading a set of images with primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have the next code to load a set of images whose streams are in a datamodel called names. My problem is when I declare the var inside the p:datatable tag seems like has nothing. Any idea?
thx!

```
<p:dataTable value="#{controlador.names}"  var="nombre" rendered="true">
                <p:column rendered="true">
                    <h:outputText value="#{nombre.stream}"/>
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{nombre.stream}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

The p:graphicImage uses another request so you need to pass an identifier to the managedBean like this.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{productManaged.products}" var="productIterated">
     <p:column>
          <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText value="#{product.pic}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <p:graphicImage value="#{productManaged.dynamicProductImage}">
               <f:param name="product_id" value="#{productIterated.id}"/>
          </p:graphicImage>
     </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Another thing that you should take care is to return something in the StreamedContent or is gonna fail. Do something like this:

```
public StreamedContent getDynamicProductImage() {
       String id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                       .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("product_id");
       if(id!=null && this.products!=null && !this.products.isEmpty()){
           Integer productId = Integer.parseInt(id);
           for(Product productTemp:this.products){
               if(productTemp.getId().equals(productId)){
                   return new DefaultStreamedContent(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(productTemp.getImage()),                            
                             productTemp.getMimeType());
               }
           }
       }
       return new DefaultStreamedContent(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(this.products.get(0).getImage()), 
                             this.products.get(0).getMimeType()); //if you return null here then it won't work!!! You have to return something.
}
```

or you can read this thread http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4163

Answer (score 1):

After wasting hours of going the the process of implementing the many solutions I found for this issue (i.e. including a param or attribute), The only solution I managed to find that actually works can be found here: [Serving Dynamic Content with PrettyFaces](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/serving-dynamic-file-content-with-prettyfaces/)

Comment: To prevent stack overflow becoming just a set of links to other sites, it would be nice if you could give a short summary of the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<h:outputText>`. You can read a stream **only once**. It cannot be re-read another time.

As to the `p:graphicImage` part, you need to feed it with a value of `DefaultStreamedContent`. Also see [this blog entry](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/dynamic-images-with-jsf/).

Comment: Is not necessary any lib?, I mean, the defaultStreamedContent arrives to the tag, but the problem doesn't disappear