# Primefaces: graphicImage not displaying when invoking page from URL (non <h:commandLink)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I’m having some trouble getting the primefaces dyanmic graphic image to display for a certain scenario where I’m trying to display an image on a facelet page (retrieved from a database) and the page is invoked by a URL (not h:commandLink). It works on other pages with requests processed through h:commandButton. However all the data but the image appears for the following scenario...

1. fundraiseView.xml (facelet page)
     html
           ...
           p:graphicImage value="#{fundraisePage.picture}"/
           ...
     /html
2. FundraisePage (request scoped backing bean with request param)

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @RequestScoped
   public class FundraisePage extends BackingBean {


     @EJB DataSBLocal dataSB;
     StreamedContent picture;


     @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
     private int id;


     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
       this.fundRaiseEO = dataSB.getFundRaiseIndividual(id);
       InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.fundRaiseEO.getPicture());
       this.setPicture(new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream, "image/jpeg"));
     }
   ```
3. When I invoke the page via http://...../faces/fundraiseView.xml?id=1 the page returns displaying all the data for id 1 but without displaying the picture. I’m sure it has to do with how I’m calling the page (since I have it working else where) however I need it to be a request initiated outside a JSF wrapped tag.

Any insight or suggestions very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Johnathan

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in another thread.

[Loading a set of images with primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905813/loading-a-set-of-images-with-primefaces)

I needed to use tag f:parm name="id" value="#{fundraisePage.id}" within the p:graphicImage tag so it accepts the id as a lookup param. As well change the value on image tag to this method in property...

public StreamedContent getImage () {

```
     FundRaise fundRaiseEO = new FundRaise();
     fundRaiseEO = dataSB.getFundRaiseIndividual(id);
     return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(fundRaiseEO.getPicture()), "image/jpeg"); \\ or whatever your image mime type.
```

}